# Lisp printing two lines instead of one line

Tags: common-lisp

This is my code:

```
(defun count-toys (sorted budget spent num-bought)
    (cond ((> spent budget) (- num-bought 1))
          ((count-toys (cdr sorted) 
                       budget 
                       (+ spent (car sorted)) 
                       (+ num-bought 1)))))

(defun maxToys (numToys budget prices)
  (setq sorted (sort prices #'<))
  (count-toys sorted budget 0 0))

(print (maxToys numToys budget prices))
```

The last line has the print statement, which prints the solution returned by the function count-toys. However, before printing the solution, lisp is also printing a blank line.

```
3
```

How can I get rid of the blank line?

Comment: PRIN1 could be used.

Comment: in maxToys the variable SORTED is undefined.

Comment: @RainerJoswig why is it undefined? Doesn't the preceding setq define it?

Comment: SETQ does not define variables. Use for example LET (let ((sorted ...)) ...)

Comment: COND usually needs a T as a positive test in the last clause. Here also the COND could be replaced by a simpler IF...

Answer (score 3):

My take on your code:

```
(defvar *prices* '(45 87 897 565 8 57 875 59))
(defvar *budget* 1000)

(defun count-toys (sorted budget spent num-bought)
  (if (not (and sorted (>= budget (+ spent (car sorted)))))
      num-bought
      (count-toys (cdr sorted) budget (+ spent (car sorted))
          (1+ num-bought))))

(defun max-toys (budget prices)
  (let ((sorted (sort (copy-list prices) #'<)))
    (count-toys sorted budget 0 0)))

(prin1 (max-toys *budget* *prices*))
```

Sample output:

```
USER> (prin1 (max-toys 100 '(5)))
1
1
USER> (prin1 (max-toys 100 '(101)))
0
0
USER> (prin1 (max-toys 100 '(70 20)))
2
2
USER> (prin1 (max-toys 100 '(70 10 20)))
3
3
USER> (prin1 (max-toys 100 '(70 10 21)))
2
2
USER> (sort *prices* #'<)
(45 57 59 87 565 875 897)
USER> (prin1 (max-toys *budget* *prices*))
5
5
```

There is no need for the variable `numToys` (it's not used). I wrote `max-toys` instead of `maxToys`: it's more 'Lispy' (but I'm not dogmatic on the matter...) And (again as Rainer said) using `prin1` instead of `print` avoids the extra blank line before the output.

Comment: There is one tiny, but more general problem, which might not matter in this snippet, with sorting the literal list in `*prices*`... any idea what that could be?

Comment: @RainerJoswig I have no clue. Please enlighten me.

Comment: @zengog Maybe Rainer means checking that `*prices*` contains only numbers, like this: `(defun check6 (list) (every #'numberp list))`. Got it from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37295340/lisp-how-to-check-if-all-the-list-is-numbers

Comment: `sort` is destructive: https://lispcookbook.github.io/cl-cookbook/data-structures.html#sort-stable-sort-sequence-test--key-function We can copy the structure before the sort: `(sort (copy-seq …))`. It might not matter here though.

Comment: The point is that SORT is a destructive operation and a quoted list is *literal data*. Literal data should be treated as constant data - in general. 1) After sorting it is undefined what the value of that variable is, since SORT may destructively modify the list. 2) the exact effects of destructively modifying literal data is undefined. That may have surprising consequences -> a commonly found thing is that a Common Lisp file compiler may merge similar literal lists to save space and then the destructive modification may have side effects which can be seen in values from other variables.

Comment: So, copy the list with COPY-LIST to create a fresh, new list or make sure that the list can be destructively modified AND will be used only once.

Comment: Me an my obsession for avoiding 'extra' variables... I'm modifying the code, using `let` instead.

Comment: ... and of course `copy-list`. Hard to get C out of my head.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `LOOP` version:

```
(defun spend-greedily (prices budget)
  (loop
     for spent = 0 then next-spent
     for count from 0
     for price in prices
     for next-spent = (+ spent price)
     while (< next-spent budget)
     finally (return
               (values count spent))))
```

Note that iteration stops when there is no more `price` item in `prices`, or when the next spending would go over budget. I also return the total amount being spent in addition to the quantity.

```
(assert (equalp
         (loop
            for budget in '(3 10 20 28 29 100)
            collect (list budget
                          (multiple-value-list
                           (spend-greedily '(5 10 13 20) budget))))
         '((3 (0 0))
           (10 (1 5))
           (20 (2 15))
           (28 (2 15))
           (29 (3 28))
           (100 (4 48)))))
```

If you sort a sequence, note that:

- `SORT` is destructive and *may reuse the original sequence storage* in any way it wants. Whether or not to copy the original sequence (`copy-seq` (or `copy-list`)) is a question of *ownership*; in case of doubt, or with literal data,  you should sort a copy.
- **But**, you must not reuse the original sequence anymore, you have to use the *return value* of `sort`. That makes sense if you consider a list as a chain of conses that `sort` is allowed to chain another way. Then your first list, which is the head of the original chain of conses, might in fact now be in the middle of the sorted list. Or, the chain structure might be preserved but the `CAR` of each list is modified. The actual side-effects that happen on a sequence are however unspecified.
- Consider using `STABLE-SORT` to control what happens for couple of items that are equal w.r.t. your comparison function: couples *(x, y)* such that neither *x < y* nor *y < x* for a custom *<*. This is not important in your case since equal numbers are indistinguishable, but with some objects you can end up with an arbitrary order for items that rely on implementation details on not on object properties.

Comment: Nice `loop` example (for me anyway). I wrote a `dolist` version (with a `return`) but yours looks cleaner.

Comment: Thank you, nice answer too.